# How do I fill/fit an object into the empty space of another (eg the center filling of a cookie)

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm not actually looking for an answer to help me currently (at least I don't think). Ive managed to move past this step with an acceptable result, but as a beginner, I suspect that there are much better and cleaner techniques of achieving the end result.

Here is my model:

[image]

My first try, I wireframed my cookie, duplicated the top half, removed the faces surrounding the center crater, and then added a face on top. This produced a model that had weird/unpleasant geometry on that face that was filled. I scrapped this

What I currently have, is a new object that scaled to roughly fit into that center, and then sculpted the object(filling) to get it to 'fit'/fill into the center. While it looks ok to me, I see that there is a lot of geometry overlapping between both objects in wireframe mode. Is this ok? I couldnt figure out how to 'snap' the faces of my surrounding faces of the 'filling' to the faces inside the cookie.

I'm just wondering what are some better approaches to this kind of situation. Thank you in advance

Comment: There almost certainly are better approaches but we'll need to see a picture of what you're trying to achieve before answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to fit your center to the cookie itself, try using the cookie as the starting point of the base of the center.

Duplicate your mesh.
[image]

Select what will become the bottom of the center.

[image]

Delete the inverse. Select the boundary loop and then relax it with Loop Tools > Relax.
[image]

[image]

Then just extrude up those outer edges, to get your basic shape, Shift + N to invert the normals once your done to get it right-side-out.

[image]

[image]

Then you can remesh what you've got, sculpt it, etc.
[image]

Comment: thank you, this was highly helpful. I appreciate the response. after trying this out, i would def do it this way next time